# Using django-socialregistration and getting 'Facebook' object has no attribute 'graph'

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

I've installed djangosocialregistration and it seemed like it was working fine for a while, but now I'm getting an error and I can't figure out where it's coming from. Inside my view I'm doing this to start looking at the API...

```
me = request.facebook.graph.get_object("me")
```

and I'm getting this...

'Facebook' object has no attribute 'graph'

After it quit working I rolled back a couple small changes I'd made, reset everything, deleted cookies and it's still not working. I'm running django 1.1.1 and it's slightly difficult for me to upgrade, not impossible though. I've been reloading a bunch trying to get it working, is there any possibility facebook throttles login connections on their end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook class in the middleware of socialregistration looks like this:

```
class Facebook(object):
    def __init__(self, user=None):
        if user is None:
            self.uid = None
        else:
            self.uid = user['uid']
            self.user = user
            self.graph = facebook.GraphAPI(user['access_token'])
```

If no user is set on `__inii__` it will simply not set `graph`. In the Middleware this should be set via:

```
fb_user = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(request.COOKIES, getattr(settings, 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID', settings.FACEBOOK_API_KEY), settings.FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY)

request.facebook = Facebook(fb_user)
```

So my guess that the cookie from Facebook is not set for your site. Maybe you add some debug logging to determine if there is a cookie from facebook or not.

Another guess would be that `request.facebook` is overwritten somewhere. Maybe you check this as well.

Comment: Yeah I'd dug into the middleware to see how it worked, so I'd seen this. On a whim I copied the Facebook class definition into my view, and that did it! So probably for some unknown reason the middleware isn't loading in the right place. I'm a little suspicious of my django version. Thanks for your help, definitely nudged me in the right direction.

Comment: @DanAncona Can you be more specific about what you changed and where? There's a bug filed on the project's github page about this problem and the author claims to have fixed it in some of his recent commits. Even using a non-PyPi version and checkout on that specific commit has not helped me track it down. I tried placing the middleware at every position in my stack of middlewares, too, and nothing has changed.

Comment: One of the problems I ran into was that I was having repeatable, consistent login problems on Windows while everything was dandy on Mac OS. I eventually tracked it down to problems in the Facebook python library. I integrated this hacked version of facebook.py and eventually got it to work:

https://gist.github.com/1190267

I set it up so that if get_user_from_cookie fails, it tries the new version. Probably not super-optimal but I had a crazy (election) deadline to hit, and it seems to work.